# Why binomial expansion approximation works?

Tags: binomial-theorem

So I have got the expansion of $$ (4+5x)^.5 = 2 + (5/4)x - (25/64)x^2 + \dots $$
I am told to use $ x = 1/10 $ to find an approximation of $ \sqrt2 $. I can do this, giving $ 181/128 $, however the last part asks: "Explain why substituting $ x = 1/10 $ into this binomial expansion leads to a valid approximation. "

The answer is said to be because $ |x| < 4/5 $. Why?

Comment: Do you know about *radius of convergence* ? This is the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual explanation has something to do with the convergence of Taylor (or Maclaurin) series but it involves quite a high-level calculus.

A not-so-satisfying answer is that you have to put the LHS into the form $k(1+ax)$ and the approximation is valid for $\lvert ax \rvert <1$

Comment: I am only at A level so i guess the not-so-satisfying answer will have to do for now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$(4-5x)^.5 = 2 + (5/4)x + (25/64)x^2+....$$

You are using a few terms of an infinite series to approximate $\sqrt 2$

$$(4-5x)^.5 =2(1-5/4 x)^{.5}$$

The Newton binomial series $$(1+x)^{\alpha}$$ converges where $|x|<1$ which in this case translates in $|5/4 x|<1$ which is satisfied with $x=1/10.$